# Improve a regex to include coupled-dashes matching

Tags: java, regex

I have this regex: `[1-9]([A-Z&&[^SLOIBZ]][0-9A-Z&&[^SLOIBZ]]\d){2}[A-Z&&[^SLOIBZ]]{2}\d{2}`, which I got from [this site](https://regex101.com/library/spvXdL) and that works as described [here](https://www.cms.gov/medicare/new-medicare-card/understanding-the-mbi-with-format.pdf).

The problem is that this regex does not support dashes, and I want to modify it accordingly. As per now, this regex matches "**1EG4TE5MK72**" but not "**1EG4-TE5-MK72**"

I improved the original regex to: `[1-9]([A-Z&&[^SLOIBZ]][0-9A-Z&&[^SLOIBZ]]\\d(-)?){2}[A-Z&&[^SLOIBZ]]{2}\\d{2}` (added `(-)?`) and now both strings are matched. But also "**1EG4TE5-MK72**" gets matched, whereas it should be invalid (not matched).

In other words: only 0 or 2 dashes are allowed.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Does a preprcessing of the String is an acceptable solution (like checking and removing the dash) or it must be solution using a single RegExp ?

Comment: @Bastien Aracil any solution. But remember, it can be 1-E-G-4-T-E-5-M-K-7-2 and it invalid, so, if we remove all - it can be valid by regex bu invalid by business rules

Comment: The format is complex, if you're not looking for an archaic regex pattern, you could try using just basic string parsing techniques.

Answer (score 2):

You can unroll it, and use a backreference to check correspondence with previous existence of dash (or not).

```
[1-9][A-Z&&[^SLOIBZ]][0-9A-Z&&[^SLOIBZ]]\d(-?)[A-Z&&[^SLOIBZ]][0-9A-Z&&[^SLOIBZ]]\d\1[A-Z&&[^SLOIBZ]]{2}\d{2}
```

**Regex Explanation**:

- `[1-9]`: number in range 1-9
- `[A-Z&&[^SLOIBZ]][0-9A-Z&&[^SLOIBZ]]\d`: your first three characters
- `(-?)`: optional dash capturing group
- `[A-Z&&[^SLOIBZ]][0-9A-Z&&[^SLOIBZ]]\d`: your middle three characters
- `\1`: backreference to the capturing group
- `[A-Z&&[^SLOIBZ]]{2}\d{2}`: your last three characters

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/HmXHUA/1).

Comment: Thank you, it works. Could you explain what "capturing group" means and how it works here?

Comment: Capturing group is a matching group, that can be recognized as such because it's delimited by parentheses. When you use it, you can reference it. If you have two captured groups, and later you want to reference the content of the first, you use `\1`. If you want to reference the second, you use `\2` instead, and so on. Since in this regex there's only one capturing group, \1 is associated to the first, namely exactly that group.

Comment: [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaregex/javaregex_capturing_groups.htm) you can find a guide that goes in depth with capturing groups, coupled with examples in java.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not looking for a regular-expression pattern, you can try the following method.

This follows the pattern, as specified in the PDF file provided.

```
Pos.    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11
Type    C   A  AN   N   A  AN   N   A   A   N   N

C  – Numeric 1 thru 9
N  – Numeric 0 thru 9 
AN – Either A or N 
A  – Alphabetic Character (A...Z); Excluding (S, L, O, I, B, Z)
```

Additionally, the following conditions are evaluated.

```
- The MBI has 11 characters.
- The MBI’s 2nd, 5th, 8th, and 9th characters are always letters.
- Characters 1, 4, 7, 10, and 11 are always numbers.
- The 3rd and 6th characters are letters or numbers.
- We don’t use dashes in the MBI.
```

I was unsure how to handle a lowercase argument—I settled with an uppercase requirement.

The *dash* separator is optional, otherwise it must contain 2, and position can be arbitrary.

I did not run any extensive tests, although *"1EG4-TE5-MK73"* will return *true*, and *"ABCD-EFG-HIJK"* will return *false*.

The logic of this evaluation works in a procedural manner—there will be an early *return* of *false* if a transition is not met—ultimately leading to a *return* of *true*.

```java
/** @param string case-sensitive; A-Z */
boolean match(String string) {
    if (string.length() < 11 || string.length() > 13) return false;
    if (string.contains("-")) {
        if (string.split("-").length != 3) return false;
        string = string.replace("-", "");
    }
    String value;
    int position = 1;
    for (char character : string.toCharArray()) {
        value = String.valueOf(character);
        switch (position) {
            case 2, 5, 8, 9 -> {
                if (!value.matches("[A-Z&&[^SLOIBZ]]")) return false;
            }
            case 1, 4, 7, 10, 11 -> {
                if (position == 1 && !value.matches("[1-9]")) return false;
                else if (!value.matches("\\d")) return false;
            }
            case 3, 6 -> {
                if (!value.matches("[A-Z\\d&&[^SLOIBZ]]")) return false;
            }
        }
        position++;
    }
    return true;
}
```